# What a process can get from touching another application's dll?

Tags: windows, procmon

Here is a screenshot of Process Monitor, which shows a process AliIM.exe is doing something with a dll of TeamViewer

[image: Process Monitor Records]

Since TeamViewer is a Remote Control app, I have some security concern, will it get my TeamViewer credentials by those actions? The process doesn't ask for admin privilege when starts up.

Process monitor log in csv format, with "show process and thread activity" enabled.

```
"Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"

"7:59:16.2471434 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","Process Start","","SUCCESS","Parent PID: 11168, Command line: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\AliWangWang\AliIM.exe"" /run:desktop, Current directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\AliWangWang\, Environment: 

"7:59:16.2471586 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","Thread Create","","SUCCESS","Thread ID: 29216"

"7:59:16.2940980 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CreateFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"

"7:59:16.2941329 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","QueryBasicInformationFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","SUCCESS","CreationTime: 10/22/2013 10:47:30 PM, LastAccessTime: 8/14/2014 2:57:05 PM, LastWriteTime: 8/4/2014 3:36:25 PM, ChangeTime: 8/14/2014 2:57:14 PM, FileAttributes: A"

"7:59:16.2941485 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CloseFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","SUCCESS",""

"7:59:16.2942881 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CreateFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Execute/Traverse, Synchronize, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened"

"7:59:16.2943492 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CreateFileMapping","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS","SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: "

"7:59:16.2944498 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CreateFileMapping","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","SUCCESS","SyncType: SyncTypeOther"

"7:59:16.2945615 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","Load Image","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","SUCCESS","Image Base: 0x6cff0000, Image Size: 0x1a000"

"7:59:16.2945812 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CloseFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\tv_w32.dll","SUCCESS",""

"7:59:16.2948406 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CreateFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\VERSION.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"

"7:59:16.2960652 PM","AliIM.exe","30332","CreateFile","C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version8\CRTDLL.dll","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a"
```

Comment: It's quite possible that the process is *forced* to load the DLL because TeamViewer wants to manipulate the process.

Comment: What does it look like when you activate additionally `Show Process and Thread activiy` in procmon? (Posting here the export of the log as CSV will make it easier to read)

Comment: What is AlilM.exe? from what I'm seeing online, it is related to malware, and as such, it may want to steal credentials from a Teamviewer session, or attempt to infect the remote host.

Comment: TeamViewer wasn't running, and the process doing the same thing to a lot of other apps everytime it starts up, so I think it's the the process's problem.

Comment: @boboes, there was a thread created before it went to the dll, csv log added

Comment: @FrankThomas, AliIM.exe is a chatting program created by Alibaba, it's not a malware but also not clean, it's known to steal information from user pc, say what programs are installed. I know that but didn't know that much it does until I installed Procmon today.

Comment: "it's known to steal information from user pc" well then there's your answer, so I'm not sure what are you expecting from us?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, it has over 100 million users, I need it to communicate with people, if this will answer your question.

Comment: It doesn't answer it, as I'm not sure what you're asking of us. If you know it's known to steal info from other applications, then of course it's going to access their files/DLLs to get that information. You seem to realize that. So, what's the question you need answered?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I want to know if it will actually get high sensitive data like TeamViewer credentials, FTP username/password (the process does same thing to FTP Client dll), etc. by touching dll of these applications, if they are running or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are observing may be the setup for an attack called [DLL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection), a process by which a malicious program can force the execution of code within another process, in this case teamviewer. This then allows attacks on the executing processes memory footprint, or alterations in its standard behaviour.

There is no easy way to tell what it wants to do, but I would surmise since its Alibaba, that it wants to be able to see connection information inside the encrypted tunnel that Teamviewer uses to protect its connection from eavsdropping. If teamviewer stores crypto keys in ram (as it likely), the program may have access to those keys, or even be able to observe login actions in realtime.

Comment: I'm enlightened. I have already decided to move the program to virtual machine, but not sure if its required to update so many accounts I ever used on my pc, now I think I have to, better to. Thank you for the explanation, and you make such a complex thing so easy to understand!

Comment: Frank, why do you think it's loading the TeamViewer DLL to prepare a DLL Injection? Shouldn't it, on the contrary, make TeamViewer to load a AliIM DLL for an attack?

Answer (score 0):

May be there are another explanations for that behaviour.

**Regular DLL search - with accidentaly same name**

Having only this trace we see that the process is seeking three dlls in the TeamViewer folder: `tv_w32.dll`, `VERSION.dll` (MS Helper DLL Windows) and `CRTDLL.dll` (MS C Runtime).

May be there is running a regular DLL search following the [search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And the TeamViewer path seems to be in the search order. Why else should AliIM.exe look for the two MS dlls in that folder?

If this is true, then the process is just looking for a tv_w32.dll and, by accident, TeamViewer has a dll with that name. (On asian pages there seem to be discussions about a tv_w32.dll which is not a part of TeamViewer).

**Any kind of missuse / attack**
Since we know, that AliIM.exe is malware it may be an attack. In this case AliIM.exe could need "only" some functionality of TeamViewer. It loads the dll and uses the internal TeamViewer functions for own purposes.

Tools like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) and [Rohtap API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) would be helpfull to track it down.